# How Can I Make Border-Bottom Transition?

Tags: html, css

I'm starting to learn html5 and css.I'm trying to make https://www.theagencyre.com/ .There is a part where there are 6 pictures saying "view our listing","the agency daily","meet our agents"...
How can I make the border-bottom transition?

Comment: This question is very vague. I don't understand why it is being upvoted. Please try to rephrase the question such that it is clear (without needing context from external websites) what you want to achieve and what you have tried. Include code if possible. For example, what transition would you want to achieve what effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a pseudo element (:after) like this:

**HTML**

```html
<div id="box">
  A Box
</div>
```

```css
#box {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
#box:after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 4px;
  width: 0;
  transition: .5s;
}
#box:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

When the user hovers over the `#box`, the width of the pseudo element changes to a full width (100%), and it is animated via the `transition` CSS rule.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/kostasx/pen/vYYYPNK?editors=1100)

I hope this helps. Let me know if you need me to clarify things in the code.

Good luck with your HTML/CSS journey beginner! :)

Comment: You're welcome. You can also mark this answer as accepted. @han
(And maybe rephrase the question a bit or add a screenshot in order for others to learn from this question too)